# LinkedIn OAuth callback url

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to create a script to read some information from the LinkedIn API. I'm using the PECL OAuth extension.

I've managed to get my request token, and auth, then it returns me to my script. However I cannot seem to get it to not be the "out-of-band" authentication with the pin number.

I've set the callback as per the docs, https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedins-oauth-details

> If the "OAuth Callback URL" is defined, this is used as the callback
>   for your request if the oauth_callback parameter is missing.  If
>   neither is set, the "out-of-band" (aka oob) experience will happen for
>   the user, and they will be given a PIN to input into your application
>   to complete the authorization process.

However this doesn't seem to make any difference. I've set my call back url on the requestToken part, and it must be working or it wouldn't redirect back to my test page.

Comment: Enable debugging of PECL OAuth via the `enableDebug()` method, then when you make the call `print_r()` the `debugInfo` field, and the `getLastResponse()` method to see that you are including the `oauth_callback` parameter in your request. Also, posting the code you are using to make the requst might help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, seems to work when I do this:

```
$token = $oauth->getRequestToken($request_url, $callback_url);
```

where `$request_url` is `https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken`, and `$callback_url` is where you want LinkedIn to redirect you when it is done authorizing.