# Linkedin OAuth callback not being called in PHP?

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

Just like [this question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560945/linkedin-oauth-callback-url), I am trying to hook up to Linked in through PHP/OAuth. I have gotten the token. Gotten everything working. But for some reason Linkedin will not return to my callback URL and asking for a PIN? help?

From the documentation this should only happen if there is no Callback url?

```
$token = $linkedInOAuth->getRequestToken();

array(5) {
  ["oauth_token"]=>
  string(36) "[valad_token]"
  ["oauth_token_secret"]=>
  string(36) "[valad_secret]"
  ["oauth_callback_confirmed"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["xoauth_request_auth_url"]=>
  string(44) "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize"
  ["oauth_expires_in"]=>
  string(3) "599"
}

$linkedInOAuth->getAuthorizeURL($token, site_url('practice/linkedin_auth_callback'));

string(169) "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=[valad_token]&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.core.me%2Fpractice%2Flinkedin_auth_callback"
```

The link is then put in a `<a href="<?= $auth_url ?>">Click here to Auth Linked in</a>` but when the user goes and logs in - it goes to the PIN page?

Comment: Did you send the callback url when you got the request token?

Comment: I found no documentation on passing it? Did I miss it?

Comment: Did you try the answer mentioned on the question you linked to?

Comment: The 'answer' was a shout out that they were having the same problem?

Comment: (I've moved the answer for this old question into a fresh answer,  as it had overwritten the original text. We welcome self-answers here, so if you have additional material to add adjacent to the accepted answer, just add it as another answer. Also, we try to preserve original questions, in case answers based upon it no longer make sense after the question is updated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like LinkedIn API uses Oauth 1.0a, you need to pass the callback url when you get the initial request token.

See [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-oauth-token)

Or take a read through the [Oauth 1.0a spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step1)

They will store it, then when the user authorises the request token, it will callback to the url stored against that request token.

Comment: And If I can strongly recommend using a plugin or a library to handle this! There is a list of plugins on linkedIn developers site!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code courtesy of WayneC's answer:

```
        $linkedInOAuth = $this->load->library('practice/linkedInOAuth', array(
            'consumer_key' => '[KEY]',
            'consumer_secret' => '[SECRET]'
                )
        );


        $linkedInOAuth->request_options = array(
            'oauth_callback' => site_url('practice/linkedin_auth_callback')
        );
        $token = $linkedInOAuth->getRequestToken();

        if ($token === FALSE) {
            show_error("Failed to get token", "502", "Failed to get Linked in Access token");
        }

        $auth_url = $linkedInOAuth->getAuthorizeURL($token, site_url('practice/linkedin_auth_callback'));
```

It uses these classes:

- LinkedINOAuth: https://github.com/petewarden/linkedinoauthexample
- OAuth: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php